# how do i pass image using image path from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, image, android-activity

i have 2 activity. 1 in which i capture image using camera and save it in memory and displays the image in imageview using path .
so i want to display the same image again in another image view of 2nd activity.
how can i do that?

here is the 1st activity

```
package com.example.shiva_000.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String Tag_Price ="tag";
    public static final String TAG_Radio ="Button";
    private String SelectedType ="";
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";

    EditText et;

    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    // Radio button
    Button button2;
    RadioGroup radio_g;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;



    static final int cam_request = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        et =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        radio_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.newoption);
        final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.usedoption);


// on click for submit
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {





                String s = et.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("Condition",SelectedType);
                i.putExtra("Price",s);
               i.putExtra("image",path);


                startActivity(i);



            }
        });


// on click for capture image
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_Intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                camera_Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_Intent, cam_request);

            }

        });


//launchSecondActivity(Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString()),null);

    }
//private void launchSecondActivity(double price ,Image image){



    // }
    public void Condition(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.newoption:
                if (checked)
                    //SelectedType = rb1.getText().toString();

                    break;
            case R.id.usedoption:
                if (checked)
                   // SelectedType = rb2.getText().toString();

                    break;
        }
    }

    private File getFile()
    {
        File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");

        if (!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File image_file = new File(folder,"cam_image.jpg");
        return image_file;


// return null;

    }


// public void

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
    }

//private void launchSecondActivity(condion , ){

//}
}
```

here is the 2nd activity

```
package com.example.shiva_000.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by shiva_000 on 11/18/2015.
 */
public class secondScreen extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        textView1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Intent ii = getIntent();
        Bundle b = ii.getExtras();

        if (b!=null)
        {
            String passed_condition = (String) b.get("Condition");
            String passed_price = (String) b.get("Price");
            //String passed_image = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
            textView1.setText("Condition : " + passed_condition);
            textView2.setText("The price is : " + passed_price + "$");
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            String image = ii.getStringExtra("image");
            //imageView.setImageDrawable();
        }

        //button.setOnClickListener();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        //String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("")






    }




  //  private void initializesecondactivity ()
    //{
       // double price = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble(MainActivity.Tag_Price);

   // }


}
```

Comment: did my answer solved ur problem @shiva ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Shiva here you have many options the first one is to create a file from the url then a bitmap and pass it to the image view

and the second solution which i recommend it to use image loader library which is helpful in case of local or remote images loading and the best library in my opinion is [Glide image loader](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

in your second activity  after getting the image path you can add one of those two options

```
String image = ii.getStringExtra("image");
File imgFile = new  File(image);

    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
```

or

```
 File imgFile = new  File(image);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imgFile).into(imageview);
```

and here is the code to rotate the bitmap

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(180);
      Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: I think i kinda got it. Can u show me how using my code?? Like edit it or something?? Pleaseeeee

Comment: i have edited my answer just copy it and past after this line String image = ii.getStringExtra("image");

Comment: omg thank you so much tony. u r a good lad. it solved but there is a tiny thing. the image is like sideways not straight. how do i straighten it?

Comment: could u please clarify more i didn't get u ?

Comment: ok this is a different question. if u look at my code it says the radiobutton for new and used. when the user selects either ,or. its not being displayed into the second screen. can you help me with that too mate.

Comment: the image that the camera captures its sideways, like in 180 degrees

Comment: yes exactly that. its rotated 180 degrees. it should be straight or how ever angle the camera captures it right?

Comment: hmm here there are two option one of the them to check ur camera code and specify the orientation you want

Comment: and the second one is to rotate the bitmap as you like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95508/discussion-between-shiva-upadhyay-and-tony).